# Найти изображение в изображении

Tags: python, pillow, pil

Имеется два изображения big.jpg и small.png. Есть вероятность что small.png содержится в big.jpg ,если содержится то без изменения яркости, контрастности, размеров итп. (наложен этой же библиотекой с пометкой watermark, то есть small.png имеет прозрачные пиксели), более того можно, но нежелательно вернуть координаты наложения.
Нужно вернуть координаты вхождения либо Fale, используя только библиотеку pillow (без дополнительных библиотек, типа numpy, skimage, cv2, mohav итд)

Comment: гугл не помог, ссылается на stackowerflow, с допотопным решением

Comment: Покажите ваше решение этой задачи, и поясните что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Приведите картинки big и small. Странно разве формат JPEG поддерживает прозрачность?

Comment: @Александр У меня решения нет, есть предположение попиксельного сравнения всего изображения, либо некоторой области (типа крестообразного размещения пикселей на small), возможно даже с игнорированием green blue, для скорости, шанс не совпадения red в искомой области будет минимален; Я думал, что такая задача должна иметь "класическое" решение, и не хотел делать велосипед. & верно jpeg не поддерживает прозрачность, мелкое изображение в формате png было наложено на большое jpg, методом watermark, то есть прозрачные пиксели как бы не накладывались.

Comment: Если у вас нет решения, то приведите хотя бы рисунки, а так вы же знаете что вам нужна либа PIL . Готовые алгоритмы под вашу задачу вряд ли в ней есть.

Comment: @Александр да я уже понял, что всё нужно ручками делать... хотел на cv2 перейти, но там тоже трабла- нет возможности накладывать пользовательские шрифты... и тут всплывает ошибка в ядре... так что уже не актуально...